# Comparing white pixels of two contours in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have to calculate white pixels and compare two contours in opencv that is one contour in first and the fifth frame then fifth and the tenth frame and so on.

I searched a lot about how to find next contour in a video. but all in vain. I am in doubt whether opencv has the function to find next contour. I am completely confused by reading the tutorials and other things.

I have done this. I doubt my logic.

```
cvFindContours(bgModel->foreground, memory, &contour, sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
if(FrameNumber%5==0)
{
for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
 {
   double area = fabs(cvContourArea(contour,CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0));
```

I dont know what to do after this. how to get next contour????

Comment: See this http://harismoonamkunnu.blogspot.in/2012/11/opencv-find-biggest-contour.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code fragment iterating contours your counour is in 'c' variable.

```
    //Contour Stuffz            
    CvMemStorage* g_storage = NULL;
    g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* contours = 0;

    cvFindContours(r2, g_storage, &contours);

    for (CvSeq* c = contours; c != NULL; c=c->h_next) {
            //*** Contour Stuff
            int nContourPoints = c->total; // Get total number of points in the chain
            if (nContourPoints > 46) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey for the help! but I have already done this. My point was to find the next contour that too in 5th 10th and so on. and compare their white pixels.

Comment: Do you need track contours? Or I still do not understand you problem? If it's tracking problem then take a look at Hausdorff distances and Hungarian algorithm. It will help you find correspondences between found contours from different frames.